# Why can't use std::cin by setting std::cin.clear() after a wrong input?

Tags: c++

I read the example code from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear and tried this:

command line input is: `w`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    double n = 5.0;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << std::cin.bad() << "|" << std::cin.fail() << "\n";
    std::cout << "hello" << "\n";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cout << std::cin.bad() << "|" << std::cin.fail() << "\n";
    std::cin >> n;   //Why can't I input again here?
    std::cout << "world" << "\n";
    std::cout << n << "\n";
}
```

I don't understand why the program finishes without allowing me to input again, I think I've use `std::cin.clear()` to reset all the "fail" states.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`clear` just resets the error-flags, but it leaves the previous input, which had led to the failure, in the buffer. Hence, the second `cin >> n` will again read the same input and will again fail. So you will not get the chance to enter new input.

You need to take errorneous characters from the buffer (in addition to calling `cin.clear()`);  Use, for example,  `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')`, which ignores every character until the first occurence of a `\n`. You could also use `fgets`, but - in contrast to `ignore` - `fgets` requires a buffer to store characters in which you are actually not interested.

Comment: Oh! So the example provided by the link uses `getline` to "eat" all the wrong charaters.

Comment: Yes, `getline` will also consume "unwanted" characters from the buffer.

Comment: See edited answer explaining why I'd prefer `ignore` over `getline` or `fgets`.

Comment: *`cin.ignore(10000, '\n')`, which ignores every character until the first occurence of a `\n`* or 10000 characters go by without a `\n`. Very likely not a problem here.

Comment: Do not hard code a value into `ignore()` when ignoring up to a line break. It is common practice to use `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` instead